# "Invite someone [over] to dinner" vs. "... for dinner"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, prepositions, dialects, dialectal

What's the difference between "invite someone [over] *to* dinner" and "invite someone [over] *for* dinner"?

Please, consider as an example:

> - [*Thank you for inviting me [over] **to** dinner*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=invited+me+over+to+dinner%2Cinvited+me+over+for+dinner&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinvited%20me%20over%20to%20dinner%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinvited%20me%20over%20for%20dinner%3B%2Cc0).
> - [*Thank you for inviting me [over] **for** dinner*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inviting+me+for+dinner%2Cinviting+me+to+dinner&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinviting%20me%20for%20dinner%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinviting%20me%20to%20dinner%3B%2Cc0).

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=invite+for+dinner%2Cinvite+to+dinner%2Cinvited+to+dinner%2Cinvited+for+dinner%2Cinvitation+for+dinner%2Cinvitation+to+dinner&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinvite%20for%20dinner%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinvite%20to%20dinner%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinvited%20to%20dinner%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinvited%20for%20dinner%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinvitation%20for%20dinner%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinvitation%20to%20dinner%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: 11 600 hits : 9680 hits makes something 'a lot more idiomatic'?

Comment: Not much difference in meaning or frequency.

Answer (score 1):

I use them interchangeably but I prefer **for** just because it reminds me of the joke in the final scene in *The Silence Of The Lambs*.

> **Hannibal Lecter**: [on telephone] I do wish we could chat longer, but... I'm having an old friend for dinner. Bye. 
>   **Clarice Starling**: Dr. Lecter?... Dr. Lecter?... Dr. Lecter?... Dr. Lecter?...